# Optimize query migrated from SQL Server

Tags: postgresql, optimization, performance, postgresql-performance

I have been working on SQL Server for more than 10 years, now I have a database which I want to confirm if it is viable to change it to PostgreSQL, this (simplified) query runs in about 100ms in SQL Server but takes 4 times longer on PostgreSQL, I am not sure if I am missing any index or command to execute it more efficiently in PostgreSQL, PostgreSQL ignored any index I tryed (like the BRIN index), the execution plan is similar to SQL Server with HASH JOINs.

Is there anything in PostgreSQL to improve the performance of this query?

```
explain analyze
select * from g where id_g in (
select distinct gID
  from (select distinct eID, TipogID
          from (select cID, vID, pID, 35 - SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Filtros.gID IS NOT NULL THEN TipogID ELSE 0 END) AS TipogID
                  from (select distinct cID, vID, pID
                          from f)fat
           cross join LATERAL (VALUES(cID), (vID), (pID))Tipos(eID)
             join g_e_arvore
                    on g_e_arvore.eID = Tipos.eID
             join (values(4123),(21888))Filtros(gID)
                    on g_e_arvore.gID = Filtros.gID
              GROUP BY cID, vID, pID
              HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Filtros.gID IS NOT NULL THEN TipogID END) >= 0)pvt
       cross join LATERAL (VALUES(cID), (vID), (pID))Tipos(eID) )pvt
  join g_e_arvore
    on g_e_arvore.eID = pvt.eID
 where (pvt.TipogID = 0 or pvt.TipogID = g_e_arvore.TipogID)
   )
```

```
Hash Join  (cost=26226.00..26426.19 rows=40 width=37) (actual time=416.577..417.881 rows=249 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (g.id_g = g_e_arvore.gid)
  ->  Seq Scan on g  (cost=0.00..175.19 rows=9519 width=37) (actual time=0.028..0.511 rows=9519 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=26225.50..26225.50 rows=40 width=4) (actual time=416.539..416.539 rows=249 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 17kB
        ->  Unique  (cost=26224.90..26225.10 rows=40 width=4) (actual time=416.387..416.508 rows=249 loops=1)
              ->  Sort  (cost=26224.90..26225.00 rows=40 width=4) (actual time=416.386..416.419 rows=1208 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: g_e_arvore.gid
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 105kB
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=24941.82..26223.84 rows=40 width=4) (actual time=397.494..416.031 rows=1208 loops=1)
                          ->  Unique  (cost=24941.41..24948.34 rows=600 width=12) (actual time=397.144..407.458 rows=2459 loops=1)
                                ->  Sort  (cost=24941.41..24943.72 rows=924 width=12) (actual time=397.142..403.422 rows=60783 loops=1)
                                      Sort Key: "*VALUES*".column1, ((35 - sum(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ("*VALUES*_2".column1 IS NOT NULL) THEN g_e_arvore_1.tipogid ELSE 0 END)))
                                      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1560kB
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=24845.87..24895.89 rows=924 width=12) (actual time=295.653..364.935 rows=60783 loops=1)
                                            ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=24845.87..24872.02 rows=308 width=20) (actual time=295.647..339.713 rows=20261 loops=1)
                                                  Group Key: f.cid, f.vid, f.pid
                                                  Filter: (count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ("*VALUES*_2".column1 IS NOT NULL) THEN g_e_arvore_1.tipogid ELSE NULL::integer END) >= 0)
                                                  ->  Sort  (cost=24845.87..24848.18 rows=923 width=20) (actual time=295.624..296.803 rows=29694 loops=1)
                                                        Sort Key: f.cid, f.vid, f.pid
                                                        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3088kB
                                                        ->  Hash Join  (cost=20624.99..24800.41 rows=923 width=20) (actual time=195.150..277.736 rows=29694 loops=1)
                                                              Hash Cond: ("*VALUES*_1".column1 = g_e_arvore_1.eid)
                                                              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=19437.06..23128.59 rows=126567 width=16) (actual time=185.929..252.949 rows=139239 loops=1)
                                                                    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=19437.06..19858.95 rows=42189 width=12) (actual time=185.921..197.357 rows=46413 loops=1)
                                                                          Group Key: f.cid, f.vid, f.pid
                                                                          ->  Seq Scan on f  (cost=0.00..16272.89 rows=421889 width=12) (actual time=0.023..28.384 rows=421889 loops=1)
                                                                    ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*_1"  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=3 loops=46413)
                                                              ->  Hash  (cost=1187.13..1187.13 rows=64 width=12) (actual time=9.206..9.207 rows=2026 loops=1)
                                                                    Buckets: 2048 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 104kB
                                                                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=0.05..1187.13 rows=64 width=12) (actual time=0.034..8.813 rows=2026 loops=1)
                                                                          Hash Cond: (g_e_arvore_1.gid = "*VALUES*_2".column1)
                                                                          ->  Seq Scan on g_e_arvore g_e_arvore_1  (cost=0.00..965.41 rows=58941 width=12) (actual time=0.009..3.171 rows=58941 loops=1)
                                                                          ->  Hash  (cost=0.03..0.03 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                                                                ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*_2"  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=2 loops=1)
                                            ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=3 loops=20261)
                          ->  Index Only Scan using g_e_arvore_pkey on g_e_arvore  (cost=0.41..2.11 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=2459)
                                Index Cond: (eid = "*VALUES*".column1)
                                Filter: ((((35 - sum(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ("*VALUES*_2".column1 IS NOT NULL) THEN g_e_arvore_1.tipogid ELSE 0 END))) = 0) OR (((35 - sum(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ("*VALUES*_2".column1 IS NOT NULL) THEN g_e_arvore_1.tipogid ELSE 0 END))) = tipogid))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 6
                                Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 1.451 ms
Execution Time: 423.008 ms
```

Comment: Consider instructions in [tag info of \[postgresql-performance\]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info)

Comment: There are two obvious low hanging fruites (but unfortunately they won't change much): the outer most `distinct` in the sub-query is useless and you can increase your `work_mem` so that the intermediate sort step won't be done on disk but in memory. I also think that this `from (select distinct cID, vID, pID                           from f) fat` is useless as well, as you are doing a `group by` on those three columns just in the next level of the query. I think that could be replaced with `select cID, vID, pID, 35 - SUM(DISTINCT ....)  from f cross join .... group by ...`

Comment: I also wonder if it would be possible to do the aggregation and joining first, and then unpivot the result of that, instead of doing two unpivot steps in the sub-query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the query becomes significantly slower when removing the two inner DISTINCT, there were no difference when removing the outer, setting work_mem to 256MB made no difference, setting to 1MB made it slower, for the second unpivot, I need to calculate TipogID and PostgreSQL (As other RDBMS) does not support DISTINCT in window function yet (version 11).